# Combining multiple rows data into a single row of particular column

Tags: mysql

I have a table something like
`

```
name    id   date        login  logout
arjun   1    2012-11-28  9-30   7-30
arjun   1    2012-11-29  9-30   8-00
arjun   1    2012-11-30  9-40   8-00`
```

i want to view this table as

```
`
name    id   date        login  logout
             2012-11-28  9-30   7-30
arjun   1    2012-11-29  9-30   8-00
             2012-11-30  9-40   8-00`
```

Is this possible? if so how?

Comment: To store in SQL? I don't know how this would be possible. If you're talking about displaying it to the user, we need more info on the technology you're using (e.g. reporting tool, website, windows app...). As a side note, it might be worth normalising your table to create a users table.

Comment: on which basis you are deciding that arjun should be displayed on second row?

Comment: this as to be done when i'm displaying it to the user, i'm doing it for the windows application

Comment: i just gave an example, not an issue if it is displayed on first row

Comment: what sort of windows application? What programming language? Do you have the application pulling data out of the database yet? This is an application question, not a database question and you haven't given information on the application

Comment: MySQL tables and rows are not to be confused with `<table>` and things like `<td rowspan=3>`.

Comment: @Preethi - can i use stored procedure?

Comment: i dont have much idea about stored prodecure

Comment: it is to retrieve an employee login and logout data for a month, i'm using core java.

Comment: @Preethi - Stored procedure is simple. You can use it like calling a function. please tell me your table name to write stored procedure...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with group_concat of mysql

```
Select 
    name , 
    id , 
    group_concat(date) as `Date`, 
    group_concat(login) as login_time, 
    group_concat(logout) as logout_time
from mytable
group by name
```

On the front end you can use loop to display according to your requirements. And if you are using php you can use explode function of php. If something else then try to find out how you can explode the cell value.

Answer (score 0):

Assume your table name is 'table55 '

Then use following query to create stored procedure

```
delimiter |
create procedure testProcedure()
BEGIN
declare flag1 int default 0;
DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
declare tempid int;
declare tempdate date;
declare tempname,templogin,templogout varchar(50);
DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR SELECT * from table55 where `name` like 'arjun' and id=1;
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;
drop table if exists mytemptable;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mytemptable ( `name` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `id` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `date` DATE NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `login` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `logout` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL);

OPEN cur1;

read_loop: LOOP
FETCH cur1 into tempname,tempid,tempdate,templogin,templogout;
if flag1=0 then
    insert into mytemptable(name,id,`date`,login,logout)  values (tempname,tempid,tempdate,templogin,templogout);
    set flag1=1;
else
    insert into mytemptable(name,id,`date`,login,logout) values ('',null,tempdate,templogin,templogout);
end if;  
IF done THEN
      LEAVE read_loop;
    END IF;

END LOOP;
select * from mytemptable;
END
|
delimiter;
```

You have to run above query only once. After that you can use following query to get required result

```
call testProcedure
```